# c++ emulate typecasting using assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, operator-overloading

This is my class --

```
class stuff
{
    private:
        char s_val = 'x';
        char e_val = 'y';
    public:
        stuff() {;}

        stuff(const string &s) {
            this->s_val = s[0];
            this->e_val = s[s.length() - 1];
        }

        stuff(const stuff &other) {
            this->s_val = other.s_val ;
            this->e_val = other.e_val ;
        }

        stuff& operator=(const stuff &other)
        {
            this->s_val = other.s_val;
            this->e_val = other.e_val;
            return *this;
        }

        stuff& operator=(const string &s)
        {
            *this = stuff(s);
            return *this ;
        }

        stuff& operator=(const char *c)
        {
            string s(c);
            *this = stuff(s);
            return *this ;
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const stuff &s)
        {
            os << s.s_val << " " << s.e_val ;
            return os ;
        }
};
```

and this is my main --

```
stuff s1("abc");
cout << s1 << endl ;
stuff s2(s1);
cout << s2 << endl ;
stuff s3 = s2 ;
cout << s3 << endl ;
stuff s4; s4 = "def" ;
cout << s4 << endl ;
// stuff s5 = "def" ; // compiler does not like it
// cout << s5 << endl ;
```

so when I say `stuff s5 = "def"` the compiler decides that I am trying to do some sort of typecasting between `string` and `stuff`, and it says --

```
error: conversion from ‘const char [4]’ to non-scalar type ‘stuff’ requested
```

But what I am actually trying to do is to emulate the statement `stuff s5("bcd")` by saying `stuff s5 = "bcd"`.

How do I achieve such coding construct ?

Comment: I'd tried to reproduce your problem and I couldn't. What's your compiler? I'm using VS 2012.

Comment: `g++ 4.8.2` it supposed to support `c++11`

Comment: Are you compiling with `--std=c++11`  ?

Comment: @cbuchart: A conforming compiler should reject this. I guess your compiler incorrectly allows two user-defined conversions (`const char*` to `string` to `stuff`) in an implicit conversion sequence. The standard specifies that only one is allowed.

Comment: Right, VS 2012 is not fully conformant, so it is probably why it works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't compile because your implicit constructor takes a `const std::string&` rather than a `const char*`. `const char*` is convertible to `const std::string`, but the compiler will only do one implicit conversion to try and fulfil your constructors. You could fix this by adding a constructor which takes a `const char*` and delegates to the string constructor (requires C++11):

```
stuff(const char* s) : stuff {std::string{s}} {}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a conversion constructor taking `const char *`. In C++11 or later, this could delegate to your existing `string` constructor:

```
stuff(const char * s) : stuff(std::string(s)) {}
```

Historically, or if you want to avoid creating a temporary string, it would probably be simplest as

```
stuff(const char * s) {
    this->s_val = s[0];
    this->e_val = s[std::strlen(s)-1];
}
```

(following your convention of assignment in the constructor body rather than direct initialisation.)

Without this, implicit conversion from a string literal won't be allowed, since it would require two user-defined conversions (`const char *` to `std::string` to `stuff`), but an implicit conversion sequence can only involve one. Explicit conversion (as in `stuff s5("bcd");`) can be done via the `string` constructor.

You could also remove your copy constructor and copy-assignment operator: they do exactly what the implicitly generated ones would do.